# Organized data in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON file where I save data using Node.js.

I want to save this data so that it looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "No One",
    "age": 26
}
```

But it is saved like this:

```
{"name": "No One", "age": 26}
```

When I save more data into it they are all saved in one line.

Is there a way to save it organized like that?

Comment: Have you looked at the format-json package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/format-json

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can prettyprint JSON by providing parameters to `JSON.stringify()`.

Many people use this kind of call to prettyprint JSON output. It's still valid JSON, it just contains indentation and newlines.

```
     JSON.stringify(person, null, 2);
```